# Add Together Elements of an Array with Same Key?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of money organized by each type of currency (bills, coins). Some of the bills and coins appear multiple times. Is there a way to go through the array to remove duplicate currency types and adding the currency values together?

My current array:

```
register.change = [[TEN,10],[QUARTER,0.25],[QUARTER,0.25],[QUARTER,0.25],[DIME,0.1],[DIME,0.1],[PENNY,0.01],[PENNY,0.01],[PENNY,0.01],[PENNY,0.01]]
```

End result:

```
register.change = [[TEN,10],[QUARTER,0.75],[DIME,0.2],[PENNY,0.04]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a map that contains the name of the coin, and the index where  you first stumbled upon that coin. The name of the coin is the key, and the index is the value. For example, the first element in the original array is a dime, so enter a key of “dime” and value 0 to the map.

Keep traversing the original array, checking for each element, wether you already saw that type of coin (if it exists in the map). If yes, take the amount of the current element, add it to the element that exists in the index value stored in the map for that key, (because you already saw that type of coin before), and splice out the current element from the array.

If not, simply add the key value to the map and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Use an object to store key-value pairs. Loop through the array with and for each pair, add the value to the previous value (if it exists) for the key. Here's the basic idea in long form:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < change.length; i++) {
  if (change[i][0] in obj) {
    obj[change[i][0]] += change[i][1];
  } else {
    obj[change[i][0]] = change[i][1];
  }
}
```

This can be simplified greatly using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (and using ES6 syntax):

```
var obj = change.reduce((acc, [key, val]) => (acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + val, acc), {});
```

Then just pass that result to [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to turn it back to an array of key-value pairs.

Putting it together:

```js
const TEN = 'TEN';
const QUARTER = 'QUARTER';
const DIME = 'DIME';
const PENNY = 'PENNY';
const change = [[TEN,10],[QUARTER,0.25],[QUARTER,0.25],[QUARTER,0.25],[DIME,0.1],[DIME,0.1],[PENNY,0.01],[PENNY,0.01],[PENNY,0.01],[PENNY,0.01]];

const output = Object.entries(change.reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + v, a), {}));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use reduce

```
var data = [['TEN', 10], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['QUARTER', 0.25], ['DIME', 0.1], ['DIME', 0.1], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01], ['PENNY', 0.01]];

    Object.values(data.reduce((a, c)=>{
        if(!a.hasOwnProperty(c[0])) { a[c[0]] = [c[0], 0]; }
        a[c[0]][1] += c[1];
        return a;
    }, {}));
```